# What's the relationship between this two-way hierarchical table and the stacked barchart?

Tags: data-visualization, two-way, tables

I have the first impression the hierarchical two way table, it throws out the gasoline, it creates a new category called "other food at home"

How to reconcile the numbers under Food at Home in the hierarchical two way table, and that of the stacked barchart?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The chart says "Percent of annual average income (before taxes) ..." while the table does not have anything about income.

Comment: Some ratios seem roughly consistent between the chart and table: self-employed workers average food at home spending seems about three times food away from home spending in both

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on Henry's comment, a difficulty here is that the table and the graph do not relate to the same thing (food expenditure for the table, annual income for the graph). In addition, as you observed, the graph adds categories that are not in the table (gazoline, and other fuels) and merges all the "food at home" subcategories into a single one.

So the table and the graph have different purposes, that's why it's not straightforward to compare them. It's entirely possible to reconcile them though, as hinted in the comment section. This is not really complicated, though it's a little dull. Here is an example of how to proceed with the "Self employed workers" category:

- from the graph, add the percentages of "food at home", "food away from home", "Personal care items", and "housekeeping supplies". For self employed workers, this is roughly $12 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 19$.
- get the proportion they represent each: $12/19 \approx 0.63$ for "food at home", $4/19 \approx 0.21$ for "food away from home", $2/19 \approx  0.105$ for "personal care items", and $1/19 \approx 0.05$ for "Housekeeping supplies".
- Compare that to the corresponding category in the table. This is roughly in line with the 61%, 22%, 10% and 7% we can observe in the table.

The difference of a few percentage points may boil down to the rounded figures in the table, to an approximate chart, and to me being off by a couple of points when visually estimating the percentages from the graph.